# "active" class somehow being removed from ".caret"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, caret

Even though in my mouseover function, it explicitly says to add the class `active` to `.caret` *(make it grey)* when "Dropdown" is hovered over and the dropdown menu hidden, when you click on "Dropdown" twice (once to show menu; once to hide) and still have your cursor over "Dropdown", the caret fails to change color (turn grey), which is odd.

The only way to rectify this is by leaving the `<span>` element and then re-entering it, at which point, it turns grey as it should. However, I would like it to turn grey under every circumstance, as long as the span element is being hovered over and the dropdown is hidden.

The problem nevertheless seems to be that the `active` class is being removed somewhere, whenever "Dropdown" is clicked on twice, but I don't know where.

Anyone know how to fix this?

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/711DqjsqtS#).

HTML:

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


                        <li class="dropdown">   
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>Dropdown</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#subtab1">1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#subtab2">2</a></li>
                            </ul><!-- END: "dropdown-menu" -->      
                        </li><!-- END: "dropdown" -->


                    </ul><!-- END: "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" -->
                </div><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
            </div><!-- END: "container" -->
        </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

CSS:

```
span {
    color:#ffffff;  
}
span.active{
    color:#bdbcae;
}
.caret{
    color:#ffffff;
}
 .caret.active{
     color:#bdbcae;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
/* START: ACCOMPLISHMENTS TELEPORT */
var counter = 0;

const EMPTY_COUNTER = 0, FULL_COUNTER = 2;

var shouldOpen = function () {
return counter === FULL_COUNTER;
};

var resetCounter = function () {
counter = EMPTY_COUNTER;
};

var incrementCounter = function () {
counter++;
};


$(document).on("click", "span", function (e) {

e.preventDefault();
if (counter==1 && !$('.dropdown-menu').is(":visible")) {
    resetCounter();
}
incrementCounter();
if (shouldOpen() || counter==1 && $('.dropdown-menu').is(":visible")) {     
    $("span ").removeClass("active"); 
    resetCounter();
} else {
    $( ".caret" ).removeClass( "active" );  
}
});
/* END: ACCOMPLISHMENTS TELEPORT */

/* START: CLICK ON SPAN/CARET  */
$( "a.dropdown-toggle" ).mousedown(function() {
if ($(event.target).closest("span").length) {
    if ($('.dropdown-menu').is(":visible") && !$( ".dropdown" ).hasClass( "active" )) {
        $( "span" ).addClass( "active" );
    }   
    if (!$('.dropdown-menu').is(":visible")) {
        $( ".caret" ).addClass( "active" ); 
    }       
} else {
    $( ".caret" ).addClass( "active" );
}
});
/* END: SPAN/CARET ON CLICK */

/* START: CARET ON HOVER */
$(document).mouseover(function() {
if ($(event.target).closest("a.dropdown-toggle").length) {
    if ($(event.target).closest("span").length) {   
        if (!$('.dropdown-menu').is(":visible")) {
            $( ".caret" ).addClass( "active" );
        } else {    
            $( ".caret" ).removeClass( "active" );
        }
    } else {
        $( ".caret" ).addClass( "active" );
        $( "span" ).removeClass( "active" );
    }       
} else {    
        $( "span" ).removeClass( "active" );
        $( ".caret" ).removeClass( "active" );              
}
});
/* END: CARET ON HOVER */
```

Comment: So all you want is to have the caret be gray when the mouse is on the dropdown and white when it is not?  Because you can do this with just css, or if you really really want a jQuery solution toggleClass would do this in like 3 lines.  I'll happily provide an answer, I just want to be sure I understand the question.  Thanks

Comment: Not exactly, in order for the caret to change color to grey, the dropdown must be hidden when the mouse hovers over the span element - the problem arises when you click on the span element twice - to show and hide the dropdown menu - because even though the dropdown menu is hidden at this point and your cursor is over the span element, the caret fails to change color.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused.  Let's forget about what the issue is and maybe just explain what you want it to do.  The caret and the link text should be white to start?  If you hover over the link it should turn gray and stay gray until you click the link or click outside the link to hide the menu?  Is that correct?

Comment: Okay, first off, the caret is where most of our attention lies. As you can see in the Bootply, hovering over "Dropdown" causes the caret to turn grey, right? Now, if you click on "Dropdown" once, the caret becomes white. Great. If you click on it again and are still hovering over "Dropdown," it stays white - this is the problem. Because we established just a second ago that if one hovers over "Dropdown" and the dropdown menu is hidden, then the caret should turn grey. Does that make sense?

Comment: K, I got it - the addition of $(".caret ").addClass("active"); within if (shouldOpen() || counter==1 && $('.dropdown-menu').is(":visible")) {} fixes it